# Solve Nested Promise in a Service Jasmine Test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an issue related to testing with nested promises.

I have this method M as below in a 'Service'

```
M(){
 M1().then (
M2();
return promise1;
)
};
```

and M2 and M1 has similar definitions like

```
        M2(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // for M1 u may call someUrl1
        $http.get(someUrl2).then(function (success) {
            deferred.resolve(success.data);
        }, function () {
            deferred.reject();
        });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

And here is the problem:
I have a test case which does below

```
spyOn(Service, 'M2').and.callThrough();

httpBackend.expectGET(SomeUrl1).respond(200,Response1, {'Content-type': 'application/json'});
httpBackend.expectGET(SomeUrl2).respond(200,Response2, {'Content-type': 'application/json'});
Service.M().then(function (Response1) {
   expect(Service.M2).toHaveBeenCalled();
// here goes some expect operations on response coming from M()
});
httpBackend.flush();
```

So as above If I call M()
The promise of only M1 is getting resolved and not the M2 ( as its nested) any idea how to also resolve the nested promise as well.

cant use $rootscope.$digest() or scope.$apply() as this is at service level.

For now the test case gives:
Method M2 has never been called
and resolves the result from M2 as a promise object but not the actual response

FYI :
The unit test on M2 /M1 alone works as has only one promise .

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue for now by removing the nesting of promises like below

```
M(){
var common ;
 M2().then(function (response2){
common  = response2;
});

 M1().then (
// use common here
return promise1;
)
};
```

and exchanged these two in my test case as M2 is resolved first

```
httpBackend.expectGET(SomeUrl2).respond(200,Response2, {'Content-type': 'application/json'});
httpBackend.expectGET(SomeUrl1).respond(200,Response1, {'Content-type': 'application/json'});
```

Comment: hi, can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201626/angular-2-test-case-console-does-not-show-up

Answer (score 0):

```
M(){
 M1().then ( function(response1) {
var common;
M2().then( function(response2){
common = response2
// resolve promise1 only if u resolved promise2 
deferred1.resolve( do somthing with common and  response1)
});
});
};
```

This is the trick which is effective resolving M2 promise use **M2().then**